# TypeError: noticias.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo una app con las apis de google news pero me manda error al querer mostrar el json de la api, en la consola si muestra los datos del json la api.

este es mi codigo

```html
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {

  
    const [noticias, setArticles] = React.useState([])
  
    React.useEffect(() => {
      console.log('useEffect')
      obtenerDatos()
    }, [])
  
    const obtenerDatos = async () => {
      const News = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=mx&apiKey=87b5009a56174c7c8e5d7535ab958835')
      const articles = await News.json()
      console.log(articles)
      setArticles(articles)

    }
    return (
      <ul>
      {noticias.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.title} {item.content}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    );
```

[image: Error que me manda]

[image: Resultado del json en consola de la api]

Comment: Deberías escribir `setArticles(articles.articles)`

Comment: Me funciono ya me muestra la información muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser porque intentas renderizar el objeto antes de que tenga los datos dentro. Es decir, cuando lo llamas en el return aun no tiene los datos del fetch.

Una posible solucion es que pongas:

```
return (
  <ul>
  {noticias && noticias.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      {item.title} {item.content}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
);
```

Mira si funciona y me dices...

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como dice Alexander G, eso que ha puesto es una buena práctica para tratar las peticiones asíncronas. Pero, a demás, tu problema es que estás asignando en la variable de las noticias más información que sólo el array de artículos.

Puede ser porque intentas renderizar el objeto antes de que tenga los datos dentro. Es decir, cuando lo llamas en el return aun no tiene los datos del fetch.

Una posible solucion es que pongas:

```
return (
  <ul>
<!-- O iteras sobre noticias.articles sin tener que actualizar más código -->
  {noticias && noticias.articles.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      {item.title} {item.content}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
);
```

O, la otra solución sería:

```
    const obtenerDatos = async () => {
      const News = await fetch('http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=mx&apiKey=87b5009a56174c7c8e5d7535ab958835')
      const articles = await News.json()
      console.log(articles)
      setArticles(articles.articles); // Asignarle directamente la propiedad 
    articles del json
      /*
      const { article } = await News.json(); Aquí lo que estamos haciendo es obtener 
      la variable articles del json de News() desestructurando 
      la propiedad entre llaves
      setArticles(article); 
      */

    }
```